# Combining two things

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

We are able to combine two things when two things happen at the same time .Like in this example

***She is in the kitchen and she is making coffee.***

to

***She is in the kitchen making coffee.***

What about if the subjects are different ? . Is it still possible to reduce the sentence 1 to the sentence 2 without changing the meaning and is sentence 2 grammatically correct?

1- ***Julia was cooking dinner and her brother was reading a book .***

to

2- ***Julia was cooking dinner her brother reading a book .***

Comment: Julia in English is usually a female name, so it would be **... *her* brother reading a book.**

Comment: My mistake sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Julia was cooking dinner her brother reading a book.** is not grammatical and does not make sense in English.

To make it grammatical do one of the following:

Julia was cooking dinner, her brother reading a book.

Julia was cooking dinner, her brother was reading a book.

Julia was cooking dinner and her brother was reading a book.

Julia was cooking dinner while her brother was reading a book.

Julia was cooking dinner while her brother read a book.

Answer (score 0):

All of your bolded sentences are grammatical.

This one:

> Julia was cooking dinner her brother reading a book.

does not mean what you might think it means.

Normally when we wish to say that one action took place while another was ongoing, and without using the word **while**, it would be like this:

> Her brother reading a book, Julia cooked dinner.

If the verb in both clauses is in the continuous, and there is no conjunction, the clauses are elliptical with the conjunction omitted and a form of BE omitted; we would typically punctuate with commas to reflect that underlying parallelism of the syntax and its omissions:

> Julia was cooking dinner, her brother, reading a book.

which could be elaborated so:

> Julia was cooking dinner <sup>(and)</sup> her brother <sup>(was)</sup> reading a book.

Comment: Thank you so what does this sentence actually mean "Julia was cooking dinner her brother reading a book."

Comment: @Talha Özden : It means "Julia was cooking dinner and her brother was reading a book."

Comment: I dont get it  . So we can use the  sentence 2 instead of  the sentence 1  .Why do we use the punctuated version  of the sentence 2 . This one " Julia was cooking dinner, her brother, reading a book"

Comment: @Talha Özden : You asked about two things that "happen at the same time". The sentence *Julia was cooking dinner and her brother was reading a book.* does not present those two activities in any marked syntactic manner as *coinciding*, happening at the same time.  *You visited the Jones household on two separate occasions, the first time seeing Julia, the second time, her brother. What were they doing when you visited?* The conjunction **and** does not imply a coinciding in the same way that a  participle clause followed by a clause in the simple past does imply it.